# how to take the average of the top 5% records in a table

Tags: dolphindb

For example, sort by the trademoney,then take the average, minimum and standard deviation of the top 5%. like each stock is calculated by group, now i got SecurityID and TradeMoney of each stock,and 5day level 2 data, which is about 30 million.

how to take the average of top 5% records in this table.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please do read the guidelines on how to ask a great question on SO. One way of getting answers is to post samples of the data you are using. Another one is to share what you've done to solve the problem...even if you have failed.

Answer (score 0):

It will be inefficient if you cyclically calculate each stock grouped by the SecurityID.
The reference simple codes are shown as below:

```py
SecurityId = `C`MS`MS`MS`IBM`IBM`C`C`C$SYMBOL
date = 2012.06.01 2012.06.01 2012.06.02 2012.06.03 2012.06.01 2012.06.02 2012.06.02 2012.06.03 2012.06.04
tradeMoney = 49.6 29.46 29.52 30.02 174.97 175.23 50.76 50.32 51.29
t = table(SecurityId,date,tradeMoney)
filter = select percentile(tradeMoney, 95) as min, max(tradeMoney)  as max from t group by SecurityId
filterMap = dict(filter.SecurityId, each(pair, filter.min, filter.max))
select avg(tradeMoney),std(tradeMoney), min(tradeMoney) from t where conditionalFilter(tradeMoney, SecurityId, filterMap) group by SecurityId
```